# What is the difference between '''@torch.no_grad()''' and '''with torch.no_grad()'''

Tags: pytorch, eval, gradient

`

```
@torch.no_grad()
def evalarc(model,dataloader):
     val_loss=0.0 
     for images,labels in tqdm(dataloader):
     .
     .
     .
```

`

vs

`

```
def evalarc(model,dataloader):
     val_loss=0.0 
     with torch.no_grad():
         for images,labels in tqdm(dataloader):
     .
     .
     .
```

`

What is the difference between the two? Will there be any change if i switch between the two?

Answer (score 0):

`@torch.no_grad()` is a function decorator that wraps the entire function, so everything that happens inside the function is done without gradient tracking.

`with torch.no_grad()` removes gradient tracking for code within the `with torch.no_grad()` block.

You can use `@torch.no_grad()` when you want everything in the function to happen without grad tracking, or use `with torch.no_grad()` when you only want to remove grad tracking from a specific part of the function.